# Dependency Injection Structuremap working on project but not working on web server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dependencies, code-injection

I have this problem on deploying my ASP.NET MVC 4 project on Web server. It always returning

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

No parameterless constructor defined for this object. 

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

but it is working in my local. I have tried to upgrade my targetframework and other structuremap dependencies since downgrading the server is not an option.

I have search and found that it is dependency that is causing the issue on other people. can you guys help me confirm the error or help me fix the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: probably missing the .NET Framework version on the server. You need to see the highest version of the .NET Framework installed on the server and then set your project to that.